# TextView Issue in ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am using textview in scrollview. I am facing issue is that I am getting first line hidden and not able to scroll it for see it.
its looking like this

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7XdY.jpg)

My XML file is like this. Please check and let me know where is I am wrong.
Thanks

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImg"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleImg"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/title" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="2dip" >

            
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topShadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" >
    </View>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomShadow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topShadow" >

       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="3dp" >

          

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="In order to succeed ..."
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5" 
                android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

           <!--  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
                android:text="- Bill Gates"
                android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
                android:textSize="18sp" /> -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomShadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/PrevioustButtonAction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/PrevioustButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/prevbotton" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
            android:background="#000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/star"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/star_on" />
        </RelativeLayout>
<View
            android:id="@+id/divider5"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
            android:background="#000" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/copybutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/copy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/copyyy" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
            android:background="#000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/share_button" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
            android:background="#000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/nextButtonAction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/nextbotton" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id1"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change your android:layout_height="0dp"  to  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: in which view I should use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Plz check you theme for this activity in styles.xml

Find `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">true</item>`  and change it to `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

Comment: There nothing in style as you have told.

Comment: So add <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some paddingTop or marginTop attribute to your TextView. Or check your layout styles in `styles.xml`

Answer (score 0):

try setting android:paddingTop="some value" for the textview

Comment: In which view you think I should use android:paddingTop="10dp" ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find out your actual problem because you are providing layout different from your actual layout shown in error image. But my suggestion is Try adding some `paddingTop` or `marginTop` attribute to your `TextView` which contains Text **"Test 1"**.

Comment: Then add those attributes in your single row item xml file.

Comment: OK then try adding marginBottom attribute to your topShadow view. If it didn't work then tell again.

Comment: I have used         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" in topShadow View but still not solved :(

Comment: You are telling It's a ListView but I am still not seeing any ListView here... Your ScrollView is the child of RelativeLayout and still your are giving weight attribute. It's not useful and so confusing. so You may have many options to try. So Try adding paddingTop, paddingBottom, marginTop, marginBottom attributes to your ScrollView and LinearLayout inside your ScrollView.

Comment: @RajubhaiRathod have you solved this ? if Yes then plz let me know what was the issue, or there is still something left.